# how to use find -ls command to list only files and not folders?

Tags: bash, shell, find, ls

I've filled the space on my quota on a shared server, I'm not aware how this could have happen and I suppose it depends on something that has been stored in some hidden folder by one of my analyses (now I have to find where..).
What is strange is that according to 'du -csh' the sum of the size of my folders is much lower than what it says 'quota'.
I would need to list all files in the server with their size, ownership and directory.
Running find -ls from the root folder makes the job, however it also lists all folders and subfolders

Is there anyway to only list files? I need to list also all files in hidden folders, many thanks

Comment: This belongs on unix.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering on your main question:

```
ls -p | grep -v /
```

Looks like you have another problem. Please run

```
lsof | grep deleted
```

When you see some strings, just restart services which is locked this files.

Comment: Many thanks, ls -p | grep -v / works but only for the files within a certain folders, not those in the subfolders. Is there anyway I can fix this?

Comment: Can you please explain what does the second code? I get many strings with 'deleted'

Comment: Then I guess right. When you restart this services disk space will available. When a some service used some file, and you delete this file it's not actually deleted from the file system until the program stops using it. About recirsive ls: ls -R -p | grep -v /

Comment: `lsof | grep "(deleted)$" | sed -re 's/^\S+\s+(\S+)\s+\S+\s+([0-9]+).*/\1\/fd\/\2/' | while read file; do sudo bash -c ": > /proc/$file"; done`. Explanation:
Grep lsof output to extract only deleted files. Sed extract the process id and filedescriptor id from each line, and create a string in format {pid}/fd/{fid}. While loop and output nothing to each file, setting them to empty.